# Automatically " + insert 1 row above" a cell once data is entered into the cell

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

In google sheets:

After I enter a value into cell A3 I would like it to automatically push the content of this row to A4 and leave A3 blank for another entry.

Image 1 would be what I have and Image 2 is what I would like to automatically happen.  TIA..this is my first go at something like this so please send the actual script or explain it like I'm 5 years old...

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LgzM.png) 
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0WQ5.png)

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(CopyofCoastalNon-RCMInvoiceTracking);
  var editedRange = e.range;
  if (editedRange.getA1Notation() === "A3") {
      sheet.insertRowBefore(2);
  }
}
```

Comment: What will the last edit of the row be every time you want the onEdit script to run

Comment: Last entries will be 2 dates, but the last entry won't be added for some time after the entry is started...so I'd prefer it populate a new row when something is added to the second to last entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "CopyofCoastalNon-RCMInvoiceTracking" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 3) {
    sh.insertRowBefore(3);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Cooper, I tried to use this and it didn't work.  Is there something I should edit/change/add to make it function?

Comment: It works the way you described in your question.  Make and edit to A3 and it adds a row before three.

Comment: Cooper!  I got it to work, I accidentally provided the name of the Spreadsheet, not that actual Sheet.  Thank you so much!

Comment: You should add Logger.log( JSON.stringify(e)); to and onEdit(e) function and learn about the event object and was it has to offer.  Every thing in the event object is already there for your using.  You can get the same information my using methods but all of those take time to execute.

Comment: You can use e.source.toast("label"); to see how the function is working or not working during the debug phase of development.  e.source is the same asusing the spreadsheet

Comment: Very new to this.  I don't know what either of those last two things are Cooper.
However, it's currently working exactly as I wanted.  Thank you.

Comment: Well try the first one and you should be able to figure out the rest